# sscanf with char array always evaluating to true

Tags: c

I am running into a bit of a problem that my sscanf line is always evaluating to true. I want it to evaluate to false if the fgets passes it a string with no digits...any advice/help here?

```
int main(void){
  int choice;
  char buffer[LINESIZE];

 while (1){
   printf("\nprompt");

   if(fgets(buffer,LINESIZE, stdin)){
        if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &choice)){
     /* do something*/ 
     else 
      /*do something else*/
```

Comment: Figure out which value is it returning exactly by assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko `sscanf` returns the number of items matched.

Comment: @op I think you're doing something else (something not in this question) wrong. `sscanf` returns 0 if nothing is matched.

Comment: sscanf doesn't really return "true" or "false", but it returns the number of %-things it managed to match, or EOF (a negative number) on end of file. Your call to sscanf will return 0 if it cant match the "%d" to anything, so there is probably something else wrong in your program.

Comment: I thought sscanf returns the number of replacements... so if no replacements zero or false? Am I getting that wrong?

Comment: Less ambiguous condition should really be:`if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &choice) == 1)` Because when sscanf returns EOF, it's *true* but that may not be what you want.

Comment: Ok that makes sense kind of but if it stores EOF as a int won't that return 1 as well?

Comment: So it returns -1 if it is EOF. Okay that helps a lot. Thank you guys so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments sscanf() returns the number of argument matched; the standard behaviour in C is that 0 is implicitly casted to FALSE and anything else is casted to true, so I guess 2 things can be happening either your string always contains an integer and it always reads something or your compiler is doing something weird and it's casting 0 to true (very strange)

but in both cases you can fix this modifying the code as follows

```
int main(void){
  int choice;
  char buffer[LINESIZE];

 while (1){
   printf("\nprompt");

   if(fgets(buffer,LINESIZE, stdin)){
        if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &choice) != 0){  // be carefull with EOF 
     /* do something*/ 
     else 
      /*do something else*/
```

you will get the wanted result and you will have a much more readable code (and correct since you don't do strange casts)